# Debugging random crashes on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I'm running Linux Mint 17 and am finding that after 30 - 180 minutes (approx) I experience random crashes which persist until I restart. Games will suddenly exit to desktop while browser windows will display a dead page error while the browser remains up.

I wondered if it might be software related and have tried installing Mint 18 on a new hard drive but I keep getting the IO Error 5 as in this [question here](https://superuser.com/questions/465136/error-number-5-input-output-error-while-installing-linux). I'm not sure if that's related or not (I've also not managed to fix it).

My question: How do I go about debugging this issue and discovering where the problem lies? I'm very confident with the terminal.

Machine:

- Intel processor
- GTX 970 graphics card
- Asus motherboard

Comment: are your disks healthy per their SMART stats, and have you attempted a filesystem check on them (fsck /dev/sdXY -f)? I always check new disks, as every once in a while you get one thats already in bad shape, and needs to be returned, or it will fail within months. your linked question stated that it was a faulty bios flash that caused the problem for them. as for your issue, look at the dmesg.log to see if there is any infomation on the last error before the crash.

Comment: I will check the new drive, thank you for the suggestion.

I will investigate the dmesg.log and google from there, thank you.

Comment: @FrankThomas Turns out it was seg-faults. I tried memtester but it didn't do anything, I waited until the bug happened and it hit error after error. I pulled one of the ram sticks and it's been fine since (I assume I got lucky with the ram stick). Thank you very much for your help.